# Updating FilesField() django with S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I want to update the FileField with new file. All the files are saved on S3.

**models.py**

```
class PrescriptionMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_PRESCRIPTION_MEDIA_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = True
    custom_domain = f'{settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'


class UploadPrescription(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(storage=PrescriptionMediaStorage())
```

**For createview i used:**

```
prescription_obj = UploadPrescription.objects.create(image=image)
prescription_obj.image = prescription_obj.image.url
prescription_obj.save()
```

**For Updateview i tried this but it's giving error**

```
UploadPrescription.objects.filter(id=prescription_id).update(image=image)
prescription_obj = UploadPrescription.objects.get(id=prescription_id)
prescription_obj.image = prescription_obj.image.url
prescription_obj.save()
```

when i tried to open the saved url in image field i got below message

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
  <Key>media/prescription/1STUSERS-BANNER.jpg</Key>
  <RequestId>5D1396D45DF8E1F7</RequestId>
  <HostId>0Chq0gedgy/o8942zo5JEz2Tp4iE6df51v0o5iY6GnNGKH3bOXb1ee9XKupKY5GYCfvankTGXHI= 
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand - why are you trying to overwrite the `image` field with the `image.url` field? Surely this will cause a plethora of issues.

Comment: @Daniel im doing it because it returned the s3 url and its easy for forntend to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not sure what you are doing here, buth this is how to properly use an `ImageField` - try these changes and see if they resolve your issue:

Don't write a url to the image field of your model. Assuming `<the_image_file>` is a valid image file, all you need is one line:

**views.py**

```
# creates and saves an UploadPresecription with the given image:
prescription_obj = UploadPrescription.objects.create(image=<the_image_file>)
```

To use the image in an `<image>` div, you can access the url like so:

**template.html**

```
<image src="{{prescription_obj.image.url}}" />
```

To replace the image on the `prescription_obj`, you can simply do this:

**views.py**

```
prescription_obj = UploadPrescription.objects.get(id=<the_id>)
prescription_obj.image = <the_new_image_file>
prescription_obj.save()
```

Note, depending on your settings, your S3 bucket may retain a version of the old image but it will no longer be associated with the updated `prescription_obj`.

Read about the `ImageField` here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/